# Min-height of list to fit at least n list items with plain CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some kind of header `div` containing a list with a dynamic number of items, and I want the header height to be fixed; if there are too many list items the `ul` will overflow the header if hovered (or else only the last 2 items are shown), that's already taking care of:

https://jsfiddle.net/te5cykdn/11/

```js
function fill(n) {
  let ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
  ul.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = i;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul:hover {
  overflow-y: visible;
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
}

ul>li:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul:not(:hover)>li:nth-last-child(n+3) {
  display: none;
}

ul>li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

ul>li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fill(1)">1 item</button>
<button onclick="fill(2)">2 items</button>
<button onclick="fill(3)">3 items</button>
<button onclick="fill(4)">4 items</button>

<div>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

But how do I set a fixed height on the header without hard-coding `px`, rather something like: *fixed height to fit at least 2 list items, say*, using plain CSS, no JavaScript?

So again, I know how to fix the height; my question is how to do it without setting fixed pixel height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider setting `line-height` for your li elements and use the same value as a multiplier:

```js
function fill(n) {
  let ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
  ul.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = i;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  height: calc(var(--n)*1.2em);
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  position: relative;
}

ul:hover {
  overflow-y: visible;
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  line-height:1.2em;
}

ul>li:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul:not(:hover)>li:nth-last-child(n+3) {
  display: none;
}

ul>li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

ul>li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fill(1)">1 item</button>
<button onclick="fill(2)">2 items</button>
<button onclick="fill(3)">3 items</button>
<button onclick="fill(4)">4 items</button>

<div style="--n:2">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly I cannot use `--n` inside the `:nth-last-child()` selector, where I would write `:nth-last-child(var(--n))` etc.

Comment: @DonFuchs you can toggle the overflow on the ul element instead: https://jsfiddle.net/38jt1sx2/

Comment: But I want (if not hovered) only the *last* n items to be shown, so I would need `ul:not(:hover)>li:nth-last-child(n+var(--n)+1)` which ain't workin'

Comment: @DonFuchs you can use flexbox to show the last item and keep the use of overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/9sLy63r2/